# Show that $x, y \to -\log(\operatorname{sigmoid}(x) - \operatorname{sigmoid}(y))$ is convex for $x > y$

Tags: convex-analysis

I've managed to essentially brute force the problem by calculating the Hessian of the function, and showing that its determinant and trace are non-negative.
This was done by using a change of variable to reduce the problem to showing that two certain polynomials are positive over a subset of $[0,1]^2$, proving that it's non-negative in a neighborhood of its zeros, and numerically checking that it's positive away from them.

This solution feels a bit too messy for me, so I was wondering if there isn't a cleaner approach one could use. (I'm aware we could use Sylvester's criterion to simplify the numerical step, but I'd like to avoid using that as well if possible.)

For reference, the expression of the Hessian is.
$$H(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
-s(1-s)(1-2s)(s-t) + s^2(1-s)^2 && -s(1-s)t(1-t) \\
-s(1-s)t(1-t) && t(1-t)(1-2t)(s-t) + t^2(1-t)^2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

where $s=\operatorname{sigmoid}(x),\ t=\operatorname{sigmoid}(y)$.

Comment: Do you have a particular sigmoid function? [Ask because difference of sigmoids might be negative, so can't take log. Maybe need absolute value of difference...]

Comment: @coffeemath $\operatorname{sigmoid}(x) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$ in this case.

Comment: Does that mean you impose one of $x<y,\ y<x$ to ensure input to log positive?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, the domain is $\mathbb R^2$ s.t $x > y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $0 \leq t < s \leq 1$.

Consider $f(s,t)=-s(1-s)(1-2s)(s-t) + s^2(1-s)^2 = s(1-s)(s^2+t-2st)$.
Each factor is nonnegative (the infimum over $s$ for the third factor occurs at $s=t$), so the (1,1) position of the Hessian is nonnegative. Analogously, the (2,2) position is nonnegative, so the trace is nonnegative.

The determinant is
$$\begin{align}g(s,t) &= -s(1-s)(1-2s)t(1-t)(1-2t)(s-t)^2  \\
& \qquad + s^2(1-s)^2t(1-t)(1-2t)(s-t) - t^2(1-t)^2s(1-s)(1-2s)(s-t) \\
&= -s(1-s)t(1-t)(s-t)^2(2st-s-t).
\end{align}$$
For the first expression I wrote the Hessian as $(a+b)(c+d)-H_{12}^2$ and noticed that $bd=H_{12}^2$. Then I used [this tool](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-st(1-s)(1-t)(1-2s)(1-2t)(s-t)%5E2+%2B+s%5E2(1-s)%5E2t(1-t)(1-2t)(s-t)+-+t%5E2(1-t)%5E2s(1-s)(1-2s)(s-t)) to simplify the expression (click *more forms* to see the one I copied). Now $s(1-s) \geq 0$, $t(1-t) \geq 0$, $(s-t)^2 \geq 0$, so for the Hessian to be nonnegative, it remains to be proven that $2st-s-t\leq0$. We have:
$$\sup_{s,t}\{2st-s-t\} = \sup_t \sup_s\{ 2st-s-t \}= \sup_t \begin{cases}t-1 & \text{if } 2t-1\geq 0 \\ -2t(1-t) & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
When $2t-1\geq 0$, the derivative with respect to $s$ is positive, so the supremum is attained at the largest possible value for $s$ (which is $s=1)$. Conversely, in the second branch you plug in the smallest possible value ($s=t$). Both branches are nonpositive.

Et voila!

Comment: Well, that was anticlimactic. But I have no complaints. Note that you can simplify the last part by writing $2st-s-t = -((1-t)s + (1-s)t)$, which is clearly nonpositive.$$ $$
The simple fact I was overlooking was that instead of trying to show that the trace was nonnegative, I could just handle the diagonal terms separately. Since it's also a necessary condition for the matrix to be positive semidefinite. ($H_{i,i} = e_i^\top H e_i \geq 0$).

Answer (score 4):

A possible approach is to use the fact that $\log \det X$ is concave for $X$ positive definite. For a proof of this statement see [Boyd & Vandenberghe](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) page 74.

Set $$ X = \begin{pmatrix} e^x & e^y \\ (1 + e^y)^{-1} & (1 + e^x)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$ such that $\det X = \text{sigmoid}(x) - \text{sigmoid}(y)$ and substitute $a = e^x$ and $b=e^y$. The characteristic polynomial is quadratic and it is a straightforward calculation to show that both eigenvalues of $X$ are positive if $\frac{a}{1+a} > \frac{b}{1+b}$.

Comment: An elegant solution, but I prefer the other answer since I wanted something more elementary, in this case.